# How can I return multiple assets after execution of my drools rule?

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rule-engine, kie

I can use kie-workbench rule engine and I created many rules. Everything is working good. But I could not be successful for returning multiple assets. Where is "LoanApplication" in RESPONSE?

My Rule :

```
package mortgages.mortgages;

import java.lang.Boolean;
import java.lang.Number;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.Integer;

//from row number: 1
rule "Row 1 Gdt2"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        f2 : Applicant( age > 18 )
    then
        f2.setAge( 18 );
        f2.setApproved( true );
        Applicant f10 = new Applicant();
        f10.setAge( 18 );
        insert( f10 );
        LoanApplication f12 = new LoanApplication();
        f12.setAmount( 20000 );
        insert( f12 );
end
```

if I call above rule by SOAP UI restful:   http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/mortgages_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

### REQUEST:

```
{
  "commands": [ 
    {
      "insert": {
        "object": {
          "Applicant": {
            "age": 20
          }
        },
        "out-identifier": "t1",
        "return-object": true
      }
    }, {
      "insert": {
        "object": {
          "Applicant": {
            "age": 22
          }
        },
        "out-identifier": "t2",
        "return-object": true
      }
    },
    {
      "fire-all-rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

### RESPONSE:

```
{
   "type": "SUCCESS",
   "msg": "Container mortgages_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT successfully called.",
   "result": {"execution-results":    {
      "results":       [
                  {
            "value": {"mortgages.mortgages.Applicant":             {
               "age": 18,
               "applicationDate": null,
               "approved": true,
               "creditRating": null,
               "name": null
            }},
            "key": "t1"
         },
                  {
            "value": {"mortgages.mortgages.Applicant":             {
               "age": 18,
               "applicationDate": null,
               "approved": true,
               "creditRating": null,
               "name": null
            }},
            "key": "t2"
         }
      ],
      "facts":       [
                  {
            "value": {"org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {"external-form": "0:73:1097496811:1097496811:73:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:mortgages.mortgages.Applicant"}},
            "key": "t1"
         },
                  {
            "value": {"org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {"external-form": "0:74:1887265498:1887265498:74:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:mortgages.mortgages.Applicant"}},
            "key": "t2"
         }
      ]
   }}
}
```

---

if you look at :

```
LoanApplication f12 = new LoanApplication();
        f12.setAmount( 20000 );
        insert( f12 );
```

this rule blocked code. I can not see value in RESPONSE  like that. How can I do that?

```
 "value": {"mortgages.mortgages.LoanApplication":             {
               "Amount": 20000...
......

.....
            }},

......
```

Answer (score 0):

To get LoanApplication object in response you have to use getobject method in  request payload, like as

```
{  "commands": [ 
{
  "insert": {
    "object": {
      "Applicant": {
        "age": 20
      }
    },
    "out-identifier": "t1",
    "return-object": true
  }
}, {
  "insert": {
    "object": {
      "Applicant": {
        "age": 22
      }
    },
    "out-identifier": "t2",
    "return-object": true
  }
},
{
  "fire-all-rules": {}
},{
     "get-objects":{ "identifier":"f12",
        "out-identifier":"result"
     }
  }]}
```

Comment: The result is the same. Nothing changes.a part of the result :  "value":             [
               {"com.burganbank.ruleengine.pricingrules.LoanApplication": {"age": 20}},
               {"mortgages.mortgages.Applicant":                {
                  "age": 18,
                  "applicationDate": null,